# Fedora 20 - bootmgfw.efi' not found - GRUB2

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, fedora

I have a problem with the bootloader after the installation of Fedora 20.
Today I've installed Fedora 20 overwritng Ubuntu 14.04 without experiencing trouble. When I rebooted the pc, I noticed that the boot loader didn't show the Windows option for booting.

I tried to modify the file */etc/grub.d/40_custom* with:

```
menuentry "Windows 8.1" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

And generate the new boot loader config file with:

> grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg

and I obtain this result:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-3c1b0b3925744bed916cd533f73a2e1c
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-3c1b0b3925744bed916cd533f73a2e1c.img
done
```

After rebooting, the item Windows 8.1 is available but I'm still getting the error:

> file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi not found

Clearly the boot loader doesn't point to the right EFI partition and I can't figure it out why.
The list of my partiton is this:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2050047   1000.0 MiB  2700  Basic data partition
   2         2050048         2459647   200.0 MiB   EF00  Partizione di siste...
   3         2582528         4630527   1000.0 MiB  ED01  Basic data partition
   4         4630528         4892671   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   5         4892672      1336092671   634.8 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   6      1857716224      1858433023   350.0 MiB   2700  
   7      1858435072      1859151871   350.0 MiB   2700  
   8      1859151872      1953521663   45.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   9      1336092672      1337116671   500.0 MiB   0700  
  10      1337116672      1857716223   248.2 GiB   8E00
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make grub2 chain-boot Win8 after upgrading Fedora18 to Fedora19?](http://superuser.com/questions/620336/how-to-make-grub2-chain-boot-win8-after-upgrading-fedora18-to-fedora19)