# cannot boot after adding grub menu entry

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, fedora, grub

I have Fedora 20 and Windows 8 installed.  I wanted to be able to dual-boot. But when I selected Windows Boot Manager in grub menu, i got:

'error file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi not found'

I could boot Windows when I selected it as default in BIOS.

I figured out, i have two boot partitions. So i copied Microsoft folder from Microsoft boot partition to Fedora /boot/efi/EFI.

I figured out UUID of my Microsoft boot partition and added

```
menuentry "Windows 8 UEFI" {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root **4013-6F8C**
chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

to /etc/grub.d/40_custom
and run these guys: grub2-mkconfig, grub2-install

because i read it here: [How to make grub2 chain-boot Win8 after upgrading Fedora18 to Fedora19?](https://superuser.com/questions/620336/how-to-make-grub2-chain-boot-win8-after-upgrading-fedora18-to-fedora19)

now i boot to grub>

i tried ls(hd0,gpa4)/ which found some linuz and initrd files, but after this command the prompt was frozen. i wrote these filenames on paper and in the next boot tried this: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2#Encountering_the_dreaded_GRUB_2_boot_prompt but after boot command i got 'error no suitable video mode found. Booting in blind mode' and got frozen. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, and in the experience of others who have asked similar questions to yours, Fedora is not reliable for controlling dual or multi boot systems. I had the same issue where after installing Fedora 20 (actually Korora 20), Fedora's grub would only boot Fedora and would give the error you got with the other installations on my system. Also, after a kernel update it wiped out the entire EFI partition of the other installations. Fortunately, I had a backup.

The solution that worked for me was to actually depend on another Linux installation's grub to manage booting Windows and Fedora. You will end up with a triple boot system with two Linux installations and one Windows -- with the partitions (I have a GPT, as you should):

1. Windows Recovery Environment
2. SystemEFI
3. Microsoft Reserved
4. Windows C
5. Windows Recovery Image
6. Linux Swap (shared by both Linux installtions
7. Fedora's `/boot/efi` (a SystemEFI just for Fedora)
8. Fedora's `/`
9. Fedora's `/home`
10. Other Linux's `/`
11. Other Linux's `/home`

I have used Voyager (Xubuntu 14.04 based), Sabayon 14.08, and OpenSuSE 13.1 to do this. I have not had a single issue with Voyager, and it comes with the GUI Grub Customizer included in the system settings control center.

I found the rest of the solution in an one obscure blog post and one post concerning Fedora on zdnet. You will need to reinstall Fedora, but this time don't mount the existing SystemEFI partition to `/boot/EFI` as you would when normally when setting up a dual boot system. Instead when you reinstall Fedora, create a new partition (same size as the existing EFI partion) and mount this partition as `/boot/efi` during the Fedora installation. Fedora will put its grub and associated files in this partition and it won't affect the other OS(s) when there is a kernel update.

After installation, Fedora will take over booting and you will probably have the same issue. But now install a more reliable Linux distro, (at least as far as booting is concerned -- I suggested Voyager 14.04 (Xubuntu 14.04 based).  This should now take over booting and will find Windows and Fedora when it sets up grub. If Fedora subsequently takes over booting after a kernel or grub package update, just adjust your UEFI boot order list to move Voyager (it will be listed as Ubuntu), or whatever distro you choose to the top of the list.